# How to get more details in log for lftp?

Tags: lftp, filezilla

I'm fighting with logging on to an FTP server with lftp, and it simply hangs as shown below, despite having tried various things. The text below is all I get from lftp

```
$ lftp 
lftp :~> debug -o log.txt -c -t 9
lftp :~> set ftp:ssl-force true
lftp :~> set ssl:verify-certificate no
lftp :~> set ftp:use-feat false
lftp :~> connect ftp.dataforsyningen.dk -p 990
lftp ftp.dataforsyningen.dk:~> login MadsSkjern          
Password: 
lftp MadsSkjern@ftp.dataforsyningen.dk:~> ls
`ls' at 0 [TLS negotiation...]
```

After ten minutes, its still hanging there without having timed out. So I abort with ctrl+c.

I tried enabling logging with the highest level, 9 ([source](https://github.com/lavv17/lftp)). But the text below is all I get (the log includes me aborting with ctrl+c).

```
$ cat log.txt
2022-11-28 18:03:10 ftp.dataforsyningen.dk ---- Resolving host address...
2022-11-28 18:03:10 ftp.dataforsyningen.dk ---- IPv6 is not supported or configured
2022-11-28 18:03:10 ftp.dataforsyningen.dk ---- 1 address found: 188.64.158.165
2022-11-28 18:03:16 ftp.dataforsyningen.dk ---- Connecting to ftp.dataforsyningen.dk (188.64.158.165) port 990
2022-11-28 18:04:16 ---- Closing control socket
```

What is going on? Did they really write a piece of software that did not log any other details than these? Or what do I need to do, to make it print more details?

For comparison, the log from Filezilla, for a similar connect attempt is 157 lines, with the highest log level.

**Version and environent details**

```
LFTP | Version 4.9.2
Libraries used: GnuTLS 3.7.3, idn2 2.3.2, Readline 8.1, zlib 1.2.11
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
```

Comment: ever find an answer to this?

Comment: No, 1) I didnt find out what was my problem with lftp, and 2) I did not find out how to get more detailed logging information.  My plan was to write a bash script that would fetch a bunch of files. But I ended up instead writing a Python script that used libftp.

Comment: I created a an issue on ther GitHub page: https://github.com/lavv17/lftp/issues/712.

Comment: Why use those `set ...` commands? Try to connect to the host in question using ssh, which has `-v` option for debugging (use `-vvv` to set maximum verbosity).

Comment: Other than that, if you are successful in accessing the server with Filezilla, then note how it is configured there, and consult `man 1 lftp` (`/tls`).